# USB Share lost after reboot

Tags: windows, usb, share

I'm having a constant problem with a shared folder on a USB powered external drive being lost after a reboot/resume. When this happens, I need to recreate the share each time.

I've seen similar questions on the net, but nobody seems to have a good answer.

I'm using this share on a secondary PC to make backups to, so it's rather important that the share remains active.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is totally the answer for you, but it's relevant to a very similar experience that I've had to deal with.  If the mapping is occurring from a logon script that needs to execute prior to the full user profile from loading, the following might apply to you:

```
Registry Key:  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Value Name:  RunLogonScriptSync
Data Type:  REG_DWORD
Value:  0 The logon script and Windows Explorer can run simultaneously.
Value:  1 Windows Explorer does not start until the logon script has finished 
        running.

Resource:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962720.aspx
```

Try setting the specified valuename to a REG_DWORD of 1.  This will force scripts and mappings to occur before loading Explorer.  Even if you're not sure that this really applies to you, give it a shot and let me know.

Hope that helps!!

FYI - There is also a similar key for HKLM that will apply to all users.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, however my secondary PC remains logged on, and on resume doesnt prompt for details. I've noticed the problem occurs always after Windows resumes with a dialog message saying that it detected a drive was plugged in. It's not supposed to say that, since my external drive is always plugged in. I suspect the drive powers down sometimes and causes this to happen.

Comment: Maybe check within device manager and see if there is a power management tab within the properties for the device driver.  If so, make sure the options related to powering it off are unchecked.  That's the last thing that I can think of.  Hopefully someone else can jump in here and assist.